# Configuration system failed to initialize

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, web-config

I'm trying to enable Code First migrations for a project in Visual Studio 2013 from the Package Manager Console. (Context: I'm trying to learn about web deployment from this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/preparing-databases))

I type in:

PM>enable-migrations

and get the following:

```
> Checking if the context targets an existing database...
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
> 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an
> exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type
> initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an
> exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException:
> Configuration system failed to initialize --->
> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized
> configuration section compilation. The type initializer for
> 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an
> exception.
```

I've tried what other Stack Overflow posts have suggested (as well as ASP.NET forums) but nothing has worked. Other posts suggest that something might be wrong with the Web.config file, but any changes I make haven't fixed the error.

Here's the beginning of my Web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this snippet to my Web.config file, but put it in the wrong place:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
          <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

It should have been a child of system.web and not between location and runtime.